# C++ Why the members are not default initialized?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

If I have a struct Foo and a struct Bar:

```cpp
struct Foo {
  int a, b;
};

struct Bar {
  Foo foo;  
  int c;
};
```

If I initialize a `Bar` and print the values I correctly get:

```cpp
int main() {
  Bar bar = {}; // I call the default constructor
  std::cout << bar.foo.a << " "; // 0
  std::cout << bar.foo.b << " "; // 0
  std::cout << bar.c << std::endl; // 0

  return 0;
}
```

But now if I declare a constructor like this:

```cpp
struct Bar {
  Bar() : c(5) {}

  Foo foo;  
  int c;
};
```

I lose the default construction of `Bar::foo` and the program outputs `32764 0 5`!

Why am I forced to dumbly initialize every member variable like this:

```cpp
struct Bar {
  Bar() : c(5) {}

  Foo foo{};  
  int c;
};
```

as long as I declare a constructor? Why doesn't the default construction works in this case?

Comment: because ... C++ ... sigh. The rules are complicated. The reasons are ... arhaic. The safe way is to always in-class initialize data members like in your last example.

Comment: How do you know members are initialized in your first case? In fact you don't. The likelihood of memory just randomly being 0 is very high as the operating system zeros out memory pages on first allocation by your program.

Comment: C++ has a motto, you only pay for what you ask.  When declaring a variable without a value, it's wasteful to actually assign some value. You only get a know value when you do so explicitly.

Comment: @ypnos • the `Bar bar = {};` will zero initialize the aggregate, because of the `= {}` which is as-if `{{0, 0}, 0}` for the aggregate.

Comment: @Eljay thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

In C++, if you have a default constructor, and the variables aren't initialized with the initializer list, then it default constructs to an indeterminate value. This is a noted behaviour which hasn't been fixed, so I assume it's either intended, or more likely accepted.

From [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization):

> ### Notes
>
> Default initialization of non-class variables with automatic and dynamic storage duration produces objects with indeterminate values (static and thread-local objects get zero initialized)
>
> References and const scalar objects cannot be default-initialized.

Comment: Default initialization not doing anything is intended. It is to avoid paying the cost of zeroing a member whose value will be replaced immediately anyway.

Comment: The first example is aggregate initialization. It results in the members being zero initialized, they do not have indeterminate values. You are thinking of `Bar bar;` which is different from `Bar bar = {};`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm talking in reference to the second example as that's what OP was asking about. I was merely explaining why the values aren't zero-initalized.